# jQuery checkbox undo solution

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

```
<table> 
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="home1">Home1</input>
     <input type="checkbox" id="home2">Home3</input>
     <input type="checkbox" id="home3">Home3</input>
     <input type="checkbox" id="home4">Home4</input>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td id="selectedhome"> </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Select" />
```

In the above code onclick of the button all the selected values of the check box should appear in the selectedhome td with a undo link next to to it and be invisible from the first td.Onselect the undo button the checkbox should go back to the initial position.How to achieve this using jquery

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. It will reset each checkbox to the default checked value it had when the page loaded.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6kFMk/1/

```
  // Display ID value of checked boxes
$('input[value=Select]').click(function() {
    var values = $('table :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join(',');
    var home = $('#selectedhome').text(values);
});

  // Reset checkboxes to initial state
$('input[value=Undo]').click(function() {
    $('table :checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = this.defaultChecked;
    });
});​
```

Comment: I wanted to get the checkboxes that are selected in the second td.And on undo put back the same to the original position in the first td

Comment: @Hulk - Are you saying that you saying that when someone checks a checkbox, the entire checkbox should move into the second `<td>`?